# Detecting SMS spoofing when there is multiple routing

Tags: spoofing, sms

How can SMS spoofing be detected? I know we can find it by message centre, but what if in the case of multiple routing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can SMS spoofing be detected?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19730/how-can-sms-spoofing-be-detected)

Comment: @mentallurg the OP is asking about something more specific

Comment: @schroeder: The question may look more specific, but also the OP is [answered in the referred thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20763/47524): *"this is eg. changed in various routing scenarios and is not a secure source of information"*. [Another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19895/47524) says: *"The problem is the protocol does not involve identity validation."*. Which means, there is no reliable way to detect SMS spoofing.

Comment: The way I'm reading it, that answer suggests that there is something more to understand. This question is asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your SMS vendor for your operator, antispoofing can be enabled/disabled by the vendor.

If home-routing is used, this needs to be considered.

Comment: This answer needs a lot of expansion. How? Why? Citations?